# What is the difference between tails and a generic live cd distro?

Tags: linux, security, livecd, tails-os

I've been considering using [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) (an acronym for: *the amnesic incognito live system*) after some researches, basically, it's a linux distribution focused on security that wipes all your data after shutdown/reboot (exactly like a live cd does) so, what is the main difference between this distribution from a generic live cd distro, does it have any other layer of security?

Comment: but is possible to do that on debian live cd (for example) by just installing tor?

Comment: tails is just a privacy / security oriented live linux. impossible to list all the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software included in Tails isn’t specific to Tails, however, it is setup in a way which is specific to tails and not found in most, if not all, other “live CD” distributions. Quoting [its documentation](https://tails.boum.org/about):

> - all software is configured to connect to the Internet through Tor
> - if an application tries to connect to the Internet directly, the connection is automatically blocked for security.

Of course you can set up any system to match the behaviour of Tails, but Tails is “secure by default” ([with caveats](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning)), which can have a significant impact especially for users trying to achieve anonymity: there is much less risk of identity leaks if the system is secure right from the start. If you take a “standard” live CD and configure it to be secure, you could end up with something as secure as Tails (or even more so), however you’re at risk during all the setup time, and perhaps even once the system is secured, if you leak identity information during the setup phase which can then be correlated to your use of the secured system.

The two bullet points quoted above don’t cover all the setup provided by Tails; see its documentation for details.